# Не могу создать 2 класса header-composition и header-social

Tags: sass, archlinux, atom, fontawesome

При создании 2 классов, например, `header-composition` и `hedaer-social` первый работает, а второй уже нет, его просто браузер не видит через консоль F12.
Если ставлю к примеру `hedaer_social`, то работает, но тут проблема другая, для добавления иконок *font-awesome* используются классы `fa fa-facebook`, `fa fa-vk b` и другие полезные иконки. Проблема в том, что они тоже работают только один раз. Редактор *Atom*, система *ArchLinux*. Куда копать?

```
<div class="header-social">
<nav class="soc">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

sass:

```
.header-social
  position: absolute
  display: -webkit-flex
  display: -ms-flex
  display: flex
  right: 0
  top: 0
  height: 100%
  border-left: rgba(#fff, .1) 1px solid
```

Консоль F12:
https://fotki.yandex.ru/next/users/mageston/album/527196/view/1511483

Comment: браузер не видит через консоль F12 - а есть чего видеть? Может, название не так пишете, как в и в данном вопросе? Или CSS не грузится? Пример кода будет полезен.

Comment: Добавил в тему код html и sass и вывод консоли chromium.

Comment: Понятнее не стало. В консоли все классы видны (раскрыт только один), в чем проблема тогда?